# Calling a component that is not displayed

Tags: react-native, components, parent-child

I need some help please.

in one of my pages I call a component. However, it is not displayed. I'm not sure what's wrong, and how to find out where exactly the error came from. I know that the code contained in the component is good since I am calling it in another screen.  I wonder if it's not because of 'parent' use

```
  <View style={{width: "66.66%"}}>
       <MapView parent={this} />
       <Text>{"ICIII"}</Text>
  </View>
```

There is just the text that is displayed (the text was here just to test). I hope someone can help me try to understand where the problem come from, I know I have a lot to learn so thank you for your time and explanations.
This is the component MapView :

```
export default class MapView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: new Animated.Value(0),
      onLoading: true,
      height: 0,
      user_id: 0,
      lang: "en",
      access_token: "",
      stats : "",
      screen_updated: 0,
      map_request_periods: "",
      map_request_periods_title: "",
      map_request_periods_val: "*"
    };
  }

  performMessageFromWebView(e) {
    if (e.nativeEvent && e.nativeEvent.data) {
      let id = e.nativeEvent.data.replace('flightId=', '');

      if (parseInt(id) > 0) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("UpdateTripsForm", {flightId: parseInt(id)}); // Open Screen UpdateTripForm.js
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  initUserData = async () => {
    let user_id = await retrieveProfileUserId();
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let user_stats = await getUserFlightStats();
    let access_token = await renewAccessToken();

    if (user_id && lang && access_token && parseInt(user_id) > 0) {
      this.setState({
        user_id: parseInt(user_id),
        lang: lang,
        stats: user_stats,
        access_token: access_token,
      });
    }
  };

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.initUserData();
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Refresh data
    this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", async (payload) => {
      let user_id = await retrieveProfileUserId();
      let user_stats = await getUserFlightStats();
      let access_token = await renewAccessToken();

      if (user_id && access_token && parseInt(user_id) > 0) {
        this.setState({
          screen_updated: this.state.screen_updated + 1,
          user_id: parseInt(user_id),
          stats: user_stats,
          access_token: access_token,
          map_request_periods: "", // Force reinitialize choice
          map_request_periods_title: "",
          map_request_periods_val: "*"
        });
        console.log(Device.DeviceType);
      }

      // Force PORTRAIT orientation
      await ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync().then(
        (data_orientation) => {
          if (parseInt(data_orientation) == parseInt(ScreenOrientation.Orientation.LANDSCAPE_LEFT) || parseInt(data_orientation) == parseInt(ScreenOrientation.Orientation.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT)) {
            ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
              ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP
            );
          }
        }
      );
    });

   // const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('this.selectedStartDate', 'this.selectedEndDate');
   //  this.setState({ this.state.selectedStartDate, this.state.selectedEndDate});

    Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 3000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    if (this.state.onLoading == true) {
      setTimeout(
        function () {
          this.setState({ onLoading: false });
        }.bind(this),
        3000
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <WebView
          geolocationEnabled={true}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          overScrollMode="never"
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://www.blzlva.org/fr/mestrips" +
              "?society_id=" + API_SOCIETYID +
              "&user_id=" + this.state.user_id +
              "&lang=" + this.state.lang +
              "&hidezoom=1" +
              "&access_token=" + this.state.access_token +
              "&screen=" + this.state.screen_updated
          }}
          originWhitelist={[
            "https://www.blzblz.org",
            "https://www.blabla.com"
          ]}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          onMessage={(m) => this.performMessageFromWebView(m)}
          style={{ marginHorizontal: 0, backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the map component which page you want to use it like following,

```
import Map from '../../map.js'
```

then use the component inside a view like following,

```
<View style={{width:100px}}>
  <Map/>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the component is already in the imports. Following your answer, I removed the " <MapView parent={this} />}" and left only " <MapView />" but I get the exact same result.

Comment: Have you changed the width prop or use flex:1 without giving width and height

Comment: I've tried to remove the width, leaving only mapview in a view with flex : 1 but the mapview (name of the called component) doesn't display, I still only have the text field

Comment: Is that map component work without imported elsewhere ?

Comment: I just checked, it returns a blank page... I'm searching what's wrong.

Comment: Just saw a yellow error '[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'singleValue.stopTracking')]' but don't get what it really means

Comment: It's just warning not an error , please check your map component and return a text to if that works then fix the issue step by step

Comment: I don't have anymore error or warning, just a blank page.i edited the code of my component in my post.

Comment: I found ! the problem was a style problem !!! Thanks for your time !